# Swift memberwise initializer - use default properties for all but one property

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift and learning the ins and outs so pardon if the question below may be obvious.

Is it possible to use a memberwise initializer to change only one property of an instance and keep everything else the default? For instance, if I have the following struct:

```
struct Size {
    var width = 0.0, height = 0.0
}
```

Is there an elegant way to only change one property e.g.

```
var size = Size(width: 5.0)
```

When I try the above I get a compiler error. To fix this, I can do:

```
var size = Size(width: 5.0, height: 0.0)
```

but it seems redundant to have to retype default values.

Comment: Make 2 different constructors.  One may accept both and the other may accept only the one.

Comment: You get the error because you haven't declared an `init` that takes only one argument.

Comment: You can also have default values in the `init` aka constructor.  That way you could write one `init` and if you don't fill in one of the values then it'll set it to the default you specify.

Answer (score 2):

This `init` has default values.

```
struct Size {
    var width = 0.0, height = 0.0

    init(width: Double = 0.0, height: Double = 0.0) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    }
}
```

You can then create the object like so:

```
var size = Size(width: 5.0)
```

Comment: With that `init`, there is no need for the two `= 0.0` on the `var` line. Though you would then need to state that they are `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

Struct has set by default initializer for all properties or for no one. If you need to make your own initializer and you set default values, just create `convenience` initializer for setting only one property:

```
struct Size {

    var width = 0.0, height = 0.0

    convenience init(width: Double) {
        self.width = width
    }

}
```

Comment: Of course with just this code, the line `var size = Size(width: 5.0, height: 0.0)` will no longer be valid.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I forget to use `convenience` keyword. Is it right now?

Comment: Try it. It's your answer. :)